# studying set I of population

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

- let x be the mean and € the standard deviation of the statistics ×1,,,,,,, xn.
- let I=(x-3€, x+3×€) and the number of items not in I is k.
- prove that n greater or equal to 9k.
- prove that the percentage of items in I more than 80percent.

Comment: Do you have any of your own ideas about how to proceed? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I solve the second part only which is 9k -k=8k so items in I are 8k÷9k×100

Comment: for the fist part I took y  and i tried to apply rule for € annd X

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x_i \not\in I$ we have $|x_i -x| \ge 3 \sigma$. Hence, 
\begin{align*}
  \sigma^2 &= \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- x)^2\\
         &\ge  \frac 1n \sum_{x_i \not\in I} (x_i - x)^2\\
         &\ge \frac 1n k \cdot 9\sigma^2\\
\iff n   &\ge 9k
\end{align*}
The percentage of items in $I$, is by definition, 
$$ \frac {n-k}n \cdot 100\% = 100\% -\frac kn \cdot 100\% \ge 100\% - \frac{100}9 \% \approx 88.89\% 
$$

Comment: nice one thanks a lot